# Sencha Cmd ERR Invalid Path (Trial Version)

Tags: extjs, extjs5

When I try to generate an ExtJS app with my trial installation it fails. It worked in the beginning. Here is what I get:

```
sencha generate app -ext sampleName F:\vs13\sampleName 

Sencha Cmd v5.1.0.26
[INF] Loading framework from F:/../../../../../ext
[ERR] Invalid Path : F:\..\..\..\..\..\ext
```

Since it is a trial version it should automatically download the framework.

*This will automatically download the Ext JS Commercial Trial package and use it to generate your application.*

According to the documentation this is the syntax:

```
sencha generate app -ext MyApp /path/to/MyApp
```

Also I checked the path variable which includes the path to the Sencha Cmd installation:

```
PATH=F:\ExtJs\bin\Sencha\Cmd\5.1.0.26;
```

I tried to restart the development machine. It did not help.

Any suggestion to solve the error "Invalid Path"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you move Sencha Cmd installation? That could be the reason because Ext library is downloaded only for the first application you create and it is cached in the Cmd installation tree. Next applications you create use this cached Ext. If you moved Cmd then it cannot find path to the cached Ext.

You can also try to uninstall Sencha Cmd and install it again.

Comment: Your answer was very close to the solution. The issue was I had to run the Cmd with "Run as Administrator" instead of the normal user mode.